# Java streams, cannot convert from Optional<BooleanExpression> to Boolean

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, boolean-logic

So my situation is that I have a Boolean evaluator. Essentially, they are all of the custom type `BooleanExpression`. Each value has a method `.evaluate(context)`, which takes in a map of variables `context`, and applies the evaluation. Evaluate always returns a `Boolean`.

I am trying to specifically use Java streams to output this data. So far, I have been able to use Java Streams to apply the `.evaluate` to every `BooleanExpression` in a list of `List<BooleanExpression>`:

```
return expressions.stream().map(e -> e.evaluate(context)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It works fine and returns something like `[true, true, false]`.

What I am trying to do now is use `stream().reduce` to take the conjunction of every element in that list. If I have a list of `[true, false, false]` I want to end up with `false`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
return expressions.stream().reduce((x, y) -> x.evaluate(context) && y.evaluate(context));
```

It should return a `Boolean`. But, it's giving me an error:

> Java streams: cannot convert from `Optional<BooleanExpression>` to `Boolean`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Could anyone lend some advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The overload of `reduce` that you are using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) returns an `Optional<BooleanExpression>` because in the case of an empty stream, it can return `Optional.empty()` to indicate that there is nothing to reduce.

Also, that overload is supposed to take a `BinaryOperator<BooleanExpression>`, which you don't seem to be giving it. You are giving it a `BiFunction<BooleanExpression, BooleanExpression, Boolean>`. The lambda you used takes two boolean expressions and returns a boolean.

To fix this. You can first map everything to `boolean`s, then reduce with `Boolean::logicalAnd`. You also need to specify a default value to return if the stream is empty:

```
return expressions.stream().map(x -> x.evaluate(context))
                           .reduce(Boolean::logicalAnd)
                           .orElse(true); // value to return if stream is empty
```

Alternatively, you can use [the other overload of `reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) that accepts an *identity* element, and pass in the identity for conjunction (`true`):

```
return expressions.stream().map(x -> x.evaluate(context))
                           .reduce(true, Boolean::logicalAnd);
```

This will return true if the stream is empty.

One more way is to use [the third overload of `reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), that takes an identity, a `BiFunction`, as well as a combiner:

```
return expressions.stream().reduce(
    true, 
    (x, y) -> x && y.evaluate(context),
    Boolean::logicalAnd);
```

This will return true if the stream is empty.

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies. I am trying to do this just by using reduce, so the third option looks promising. However, when I try that, it highlights ```x.evaluate``` with ```The method evaluate(Map<String,Boolean>) is undefined for the type Boolean```. However, y seems to be fine. Strange.

Comment: @Zvonimir Oops! I made a mistake. See the edit.

Comment: That works great! Fantastic, thanks so much for the help! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce returns an optional because maybe nothing came out.

```
Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
```

Try `return expressions.stream().reduce((x, y) -> x.evaluate(context) && y.evaluate(context)).get();` if you're certain that something will be produced or use the `Optional` operators `.map`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, for some reason if I add ```.get()``` I get: ```Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to BooleanExpression```. :(

Comment: `&&` evaluates to a boolean.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for the reply -- yes the method returns a Boolean. That's why I'm very confused at the moment. Using ```get()``` highlights the entire return with ```Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to BooleanExpression```, whereas something like ```.orElse(true)``` just highlights ```x.evaluate(context) && y.evaluate(context)``` with the same error. Also, the ```orElse(true)``` has an error ```The method orElse(BooleanExpression) in the type Optional<BooleanExpression> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)```.